# XSD Element Not Null or Empty Constraint For Xml?

Tags: xml, xsd

This is my sample XML Code:

```
<bestContact>
<firstName><![CDATA[12345]]></firstName>
<lastName />
</bestContact>
```

I am using:

```
<xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" nillable="false"/>
```

The XSD Should be validate `lastName` as not null or empty.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try

```
<xs:element name="lastName" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
  <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:minLength value="1"/>
     </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Using this I get "Element 'lastName' has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is allowed for an element." I think there is a problem on using type="xs:string" in the container element.

Answer (score 22):

```
<xsd:element name="lastName" type="NonEmptyString" nillable="false"/>

<xsd:simpleType name="NonEmptyString">
  <xsd:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xsd:minLength value="1" />
    <xsd:pattern value=".*[^\s].*" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: I like this better than the 2 offered by Gab, this one works for me.Since I was looking for an expression that just got rid of the leading spaces, not the spaces in between text

Comment: I think you can just replace this regex by `\S+` as Gab pointed out.

Answer (score 11):

This is IMHO a better pattern:

```
<xs:simpleType name="NonEmptyString">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="^(?!\s*$).+" />
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

or

```
<xs:simpleType name="NonEmptyStringWithoutSpace">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\S+"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: is there any advantage to your first proposal over the second one?

Comment: Well a (non empty) blanck string will be allowed by the 1st one but not the 2nd. It just depends on your needs

Comment: how can i have a  <xs:attribute name="" type="MDFS" use="optional" /> optional,  pattern                                                                                            
         <xs:simpleType name="MDFS">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z]\d{3}" />
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>,                                                                                                       since it is optional, having a type, it can not be null !!!! is it possible being null having a type pattern ?

Comment: (? will lead to an invalid xsd so the 1st solution will not work

Answer (score 9):

@Kamal has given you basically right answer here. This is why -  `nillable` always seems to cause problems. Effectively, you can consider `nillable` as meaning **allow the `xsi:nil` attribute on this element**. The [XML Schema spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#Nils) describes nillable as an out of band signal - it's basically used to indicate **NULL** to databases.

What you want is an element that must be at least one character long as given by @Kamal

Answer (score 0):

This was my favourite solution.

```xml
<xs:simpleType name="NonEmptyString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[\s\S]*[^ ][\s\S]*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```