# Why use a regex if you need an nonempty element?

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I need to specify that certain XML elements always not be null and not be empty.  I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408158/xsd-element-not-null-or-empty-constraint-for-xml), which suggests using a restriction to set `minLength` to 1.  But a couple of posters suggested using a pattern restriction with a regular expression either instead of or in addition to the `minLength` restriction.  What is the advantage of a regex over `minLength` to accomplish this?

Comment: All I need is to make sure that there is at least one non-whitespace character.  Embedded whitespace is valid.

Comment: Then you'll need to use regex.   See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35707836/290085) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using regex allows one to differentiate between whitespace and non-whitespace characters in specifying validity rather than relying on length alone.**

For example, without regex, `NonEmptyString`,

```
<xs:simpleType name="NonEmptyString">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="1" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

*would* allow `<x> </x>` (but not `<x/>` or `<x></x>`).  ***This may or may not be what you want.***

While, with regex, `NonEmptyStringWithoutSpaces`,

```
<xs:simpleType name="NonEmptyStringWithoutSpaces">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\S+"/>  <!-- one or more non-whitespace chars -->
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

would *not* allow `<x> </x>` (and still allow not `<x/>` or `<x></x>` as well).  Note, however, that this would also not allow `<x>A B</x>`.  ***This is probably not what you want.***

If you'd like to allow embedded spaces, you could use

```
<xs:simpleType name="NonEmptyNonBlankString">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value=".*\S.*"/>  <!-- at least one non-whitespace char -->
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

to *not* allow `<x> </x>`, `<x/>`, or `<x></x>`, while allowing `<x>A B</x>` and `<x>   A </x>`.  Or, without regex, you could use a [`xs:whiteSpace`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html#rf-whiteSpace) facet:

```
<xs:simpleType name="NonEmptyNonBlankString">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="1" />
    <xs:whiteSpace value='collapse'/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

***This is probably what you want.***

Comment: Thank you very much.  I tested that, and it appeared that a value consisting of a single blank space was rejected, which made me think that values were automatically being trimmed.  But that's probably a dangerous assumption, and the regex is more reliable.

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON, whitespace may be trimmed or not, depending on the value of the whitespace facet for the base type of your simple type definition.