# Validating XML against XSD is slow for long strings if maxLength and pattern restrictions are defined

Tags: java, xsd, xml-parsing, jaxb, xsd-validation

We have the following simple type defined in our xsd:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="SimpleText255NotBlankType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">String of maximum 255 characters, not blank</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
            <xsd:pattern value=".*[^\s].*"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The problem is when a really long string (ca. 1000000 characters) is provided as a value in the input xml, we would assume that it is regarded invalid quickly because of the length. Actually the validation takes several minutes since the regex gets evaluated before the maxLength restriction.

We found a workaround for the issue if we define the simpleType this way:

```
     <xsd:simpleType name="SimpleText255Type">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">String of maximum 255 characters</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
            <xsd:pattern value=".{1,255}"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="SimpleText255NotBlankType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">String of maximum 255 characters, not blank</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="SimpleText255Type">
            <xsd:pattern value=".*[^\s].*"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

The workaround only works because the Xerces implementation of the XSSimpleType builds a Vector of the regex patterns and the `.{1,255}` pattern will be evaluated first and it fails relatively quickly thus the time consuming second regex wont be checked.

Has anyone run into the same problem and found a solution, which doesn't depends on the implementation of xsd validation? Or is there any way to order the validation of xsd:restriction-s in jaxb (so that maxLength could be validated before checking the pattern)?

We created an example application on github:
https://github.com/petmaark/xsd-pattern-validation-test

Comment: Maybe a better regex for the testing of "non-blankness" like `"^(?!\s*$).+"` would be already enough.

Comment: *FYI:* `[^\s]` is better written as `\S`

Comment: Isn't specifying `<xsd:minLength value="1"/><xsd:maxLength value="255"/>` **redundant** with `<xsd:pattern value=".{1,255}"/>`? Remove the `<xsd:pattern>`

Comment: @thomas-kläger that could be good but unfortunately regex validation in XSD is limited and does not suport lookaheads (https://regular-expressions.mobi/xml.html?wlr=1) so we can’t use that regex.

Comment: @andreas that pattern is indeed redundant, it is needed because without it the evaluation order for the restrictions would be: 1. ".*[^\s].*" (slow, valid) 2.maxLength (invalid). With defining length as a separate regex on a parent type that regex will be the first to get evaluated and it fails quickly, thats why the workaround can be a solition

Comment: But it seems that other can use that pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17806714/5646962

Comment: @ThomasKläger i just checked it with jaxp and even with XMLSpy and both claims that the `^(?!\s*$).+` is not a valid XML regular expression

Comment: I think your complaint is reasonable, you have done some good research and you have found an ingenious workaround. AFAICT the XML Schema spec does not require facets to be validated in any particular order, so I think you will probably get the best results by asking this question to the team who develop the Xerces parser. If you are able to use a different XML parser, that might be worth exploring - I think IBM ships a JVM that uses something other than Xerces.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @kimbert, we issued a ticket for the Xerces team, we shall see if they have another workaround. As for the JVM change, we are not able use the one that IBM ships because of our client.

Answer (score 0):

Xerces2 supports XSD 1.1. Unfortunately, that version is not in the official maven central repository. You can use a third-party repository(You will need icu4j as well). If it is not a viable solution for you, you can download the official stable version from the [Xerces website](http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi)(Xerces2 Java 2.12.0 (XML Schema 1.1)), and install it to your local maven repository.

```xml
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opengis.cite.xerces/xercesImpl-xsd11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opengis.cite.xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl-xsd11</artifactId>
            <version>2.12-beta-r1667115</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Needed for string-length -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

You will need to replace your schema version as well.

```java
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/XML/XMLSchema/v1.1");
```

You can use assertions in XSD 1.1(there are other useful new features in XSD 1.1 as well, that you can benefit from).  Now you can specify the evaluation order of your validation rules.

```xml
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <!--<xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="255"/>
            <xs:pattern value=".*[^\s].*"/>-->

            <xs:assertion test="(string-length($value) >= 1) and (string-length($value) &lt;= 255) and (matches($value, '.*[^\s].*')) "/>

</xs:restriction>
```

I hope this is a viable solution and I could help you!